# ajax post to php results in 406 when data contains <meta

Tags: php, ajax, http-status-code-406

`<meta` (is what is typed into the form field) form submitted thru jQuery ajax

On my dev server (php 5.3.5) it works fine. On the production server (php 5.3.27) it returns 406.

I can't seem to troubleshoot this on the dev server because the server returns 406 before php is invoked.

When form data is submitted without `<meta`, it works no problem.

The form also has a wysiwyg editor and markup tags like `<h1>` cause no error.

I made a basic form without ajax, it posts `<meta` without problem.

How can I troubleshoot this further to see what the server thinks it is receiving and why it thinks it is NOT ACCEPTABLE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A browser will indicate what it can accept via a number of `Accept` headers in the request. If the server wants to return something that the browser will not accept it issues a 406 response.

Check the headers being sent to the server from your browser (Firebug or Chrome's developer tools will help)

Check the server configuration (specifically any `.htaccess` files) and make sure that the server can respond in an appropriate way.

Comment: Chrome browser was sending  

  Accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01  
based on ajax setting dataType:'json'  
  
PHP server response was sending  
  Content-Type:text/html  
which should have been accepted due to the wildcard.  

anyhow...  it has magically "fixed" itself and posts containing <meta return 200 status, but not sure why it fixed itself. Perhaps the hosted server had issues before, or the browser had memory issues, etc. Since this worked fine on a local dev server, but not on the hosted prod server, i assume it was a remote server issue. Thanks for your help